# Vue 3 Vuex 4 with TypeScript and Composition APi in store is just State without getters and mutations, actions

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Vue 3 Vuex 4 with TypeScript and Composition APi in store is just State without getters and mutations, actions

I just got from Store module State in Vue devtools and never get actions, getters, mutations.

Structure of my store is
export default {
namespaced: true,
state() {},
getters: {},
actions: {},
mutations: {},
}

I heard that for Vue 3 with Vuex 4 store with Typescript is needed that all state, mutations, getters and actions should be in 1 file and then exported to store.ts and then used in component.

Is it true?

Does anybody can provide the example of such solution, please?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem, it's unclear what happens on your end.

Comment: Is there any specific need to use vuex ? as vue 3 with composition api, pinia is more robust and easy to manage. also less verbose